# Word Play Question

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I created a function that takes a word and a string of 'forbidden' letters, and returns True if the word doesn't use any of the letter.

```
def avoids(word,forbidden):
    for letter in word:
        if letter in forbidden:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

I want to modify this so instead of using 'forbidden' as the letters to avoid, the user will be prompted to place a couple of letters and print the number of words that don't contain any of them. I also have a .txt document that contain these words to make it interesting.

This is what I've came up with which is wrong. I would like some assistance and education if possible since my 'online' teacher is never around to assist. Please Help :)

```
def word_no_forbidden():
    forbidden = input('pick 5 letters')
    fin = open('words1.txt')
    no_forbidden_word = 0
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        for letter in word:

            if forbidden in word:
                continue
            print word
```

This is the error I get and I understand it but, I'm not sure how else to approach this...

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
     word_no_forbidden()
  File "C:/Python27/test.py", line 9, in word_no_forbidden
     if forbidden in word:
  TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Comment: Side note: Particularly when posting Python code, it pays to make sure you're preserving your indentation.  After pasting in code, selecting the code you pasted and clicking the editor's `{}` button or typing Ctrl+K will result in a code block with the same indentation as what you pasted.

Comment: Note your original function could be written as `return any(letter in forbidden for letter in word)` or `return set(word).isdisjoint(forbidden)`.

Comment: @JohnFlatness I'm illiterate at this site obviously. My apologies for my lack of indentation... I will definitely do that next time.

Comment: What _exactly_ did you type in for `forbidden`? What version of Python are you on?

Comment: @agf
I typed: 'a','b','c','d','e'     

I then want forbidden to equal those 5 letters and print out the words from a .txt document that doesn't have those letters.
I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Just type in `abcde` and change `input` to `raw_input`. You want a string, so use the function that returns a string. Your function is still wrong, think about what it's doing `if forbidden in word`. I'm not going to give you all the answers as this is homework, like your other questions (_please_ remember to add the homework tag)

Comment: @agf I did that and my output was the entire list of words contained in the .txt file. This is my conflict... How do I code this so it only prints out the words that do not contain those letters?(abcde)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3715/discussion-between-g-g-and-agf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def word_no_forbidden():
    forbidden = raw_input('pick 5 letters')
    fin = open('words1.txt')
    no_forbidden_word = 0
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        for letter in list(word):
            if letter in forbidden:
                break
        else:
            print word
```

**NOTE:**

1> As winston said use `raw_input`

2> In case you want to traverse a string use `list(your_string)` to get a list of characters

3> the `else` here executes only when our `for letter in list(word)` loop completes without ever going to break( in other words, none of the letters are in forbidden)

Comment: This is the output I'm looking for! Would you mind explaining for letter in list(word):
            if letter in forbidden:
                break
        else:
            print word

Comment: I still have issues understanding that concept 'traverse.' So you traverse a string and is this always the case where you to type list(your_string)? Pardon my illiteracy, how do you shade 'list(your_string) within a comment?

Comment: @G.G : about shading the code click the little help buttun you see near your comment box

Comment: Why do we need to traverse the string when word = line.strip() which means to me..for every letter in word: if that letter is in forbidden(abcde),we disregard. At this point, you did a break... does 'continue' the same for output and exclude the else: and just print word?

Comment: I think you are confusing split() and strip(). In any case both will not work for you. About break and continue, read [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3716/discussion-between-vivek-and-g-g)

Comment: @agf Yes, this is homework but I don't care about the answer as much as I do the explanation to how we obtained that solution. I'm not a cheater or taking credit for anyone's work. I simply want to understand from my mistakes whether or not I'm heading in the right direction. If I'm given the answer, it means nothing unless I know myself how to get there. I use this as a last resort when I've exhausted my efforts and it takes 48hrs for my instructor to respond to my questions.

Comment: @agf : but he did really try. Moreover, from his questions i got it that hints aren't going to work for him, he doesn't know much python.So I helped him only for this time. I do get your point though.

Comment: @G.G It's natural to want as much help as you can get, my only issue is this question will never be helpful to anyone else and so is "too localized". I was just suggesting to vivek that the opinion of the community on this site is not to give complete solutions to homework problems.

Comment: There is no need to use `list(word)`

Answer (score 2):

My guess...

You are python 2.x

When you ran the program you typed in:

```
'a','b','c','d'
```

On python 2.x, you want to use raw_input not input. That'll give a string of exactly what you type in. As it is python will try to interpret whatever you right as a python expression which is dangerous and generally a bad idea.

Your second problem is that you've reversed your line of code from the first example, `letter in forbidden`, so that it becomes `forbidden in word` Not the same thing.

Comment: Understood. I know better. I just got desperate :/

Answer (score 1):

To read in a string from the user, you should use `raw_input`, not `input`. `input` tries to actually evaluate the string the user types as Python code, and can result in you getting a datatype you don't expect (or other, worse things).

In contrast, `raw_input` always returns a string.

(Note: this applies for Python 2.x only. Starting with Python 3, `raw_input` is renamed to `input`, and there's no function that does what `input` used to do.)

Comment: Thanks, John. I always wanted to know how that worked between those two. I will remember that now.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of the code

```
for letter in word:
  if forbidden in word:
```

You should be doing

```
for letter in forbidden:
  if letter in word:
```

What you want to do is check, for every letter in the ones the users entered, if it is in the word read from the file, skip the word and go to the next one. There are more pythonic ways of doing this but I think this is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I appreciate the explanation. When I write it this way, I still receive all the words with the letters I don't want to produce.